# Send email to users that checked 'yes' - php and modx

Tags: php, mysql, email, modx

I have a database of 'user comments' that holds the comment, the userId, true/false for if they want to be emailed.

My issue is that if a user comments on a post 5 times, they are in that database 5 times and thus, they get 5 of the same emails. Here is my setup:

Find users in the database that want to be emailed about this comment

```
$ab = $modx->newQuery('Comments');
$ab->leftJoin('modUserProfile','Profile',array('Profile.internalKey = Comments.author'));
$ab->leftJoin('Bulletin','Bulletin',array('Bulletin.id = Comments.bulletin_id'));
$ab->where(array('Comments.bulletin_id' => $bullId));
$ab->where(array('Comments.email' => 1));
$ab->select(array('Comments.*','Profile.fullname as fullname' , 'Profile.email as email' , 'Bulletin.title as title'));
$emailList = $modx->getCollection('Comments',$ab);
```

Now, email them

```
foreach ($emailList as $e){
$modx->getService('mail', 'mail.modPHPMailer');
$modx->mail->address('to',$e->email);
$modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_BODY,$message);
$modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_SUBJECT,'A new comment has been posted!');}
```

What should I use to email the users so that they only get 1 email regardless of the amount of comments they have made? Please let me know if the above is not clear enough. Thank you!!

Comment: You're looping through the results of `$emailList`. Don't loop, just send the email if result is `$emailList >= 1`

Comment: @relentless thanks for this. I've just had a chance to attempt your resolution but I am a bit confused as to how I would capture the email address of the user? If I don't loop (which makes sense) then how can I get the address of those that fit `$emailList >= 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add a groupby....

```
$ab->groupby('email');
```

after your select

Comment: Thank you Sean, this was the perfect solution. I read up on this and it's very helpful. Thanks again.